# Want to get the MAX(ID) from a db table datewise, but it returns only same ID in sqlserver 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to get the maximum ID from a database table and want to show it on win form load.
I am using the following query to get the maximum ID.

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),0)+1  FROM StockMain WHERE VRDATE = '2013-01-30'
```

Above should have to return the maximum ID of today., e.g if I this statement is excutes for the first time it will return me the Value '1'. After saving first record on ID = '1' it should give me MAX(ID) = '2'. But it returns me the value 1.

Any suggestion or solutions????

Comment: That select statement will return no result if there are no matching rows. It *won't* return 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess... but what data type is `VRDATE`?  Does it include a time component, or is it just a date?

If it includes a time component indicating when you saved the record, it won't pass the `VRDATE = '2013-01-30'` check, since this defaults to a time of midnight.  Since the times aren't identical, they are not equal.

Instead, try:

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),0)+1  
FROM StockMain 
WHERE VRDATE BETWEEN '2013-01-30' AND '2013-02-01'
```

Next question... have you considered using an `IDENTITY` column instead of managing the ID values manually?

Comment: Data type of VRDATE is DateTime. This ID column shows the Recent ID of the day, and ID values is set manually.